# MySQL Automatic update in the same table but different column when updating value in one column

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have a table named `mp1` but want table `mp1` to look like `mp2`. When updating status column for both `id=2, id=3`. However i want `code` column to update automatically upon update. I'm aware that i can use trigger but I've read it is not possible to do when executing an `update` statement?

statements:

`update mp1 set status = NULL where id = 2;`
`update mp1 set status = 1 where id = 3;`

mp1 table:

```
id    status   code
1     1        01
2     Null     Null
3     12       01
```

mp2 table:

```
id    status   code
1     1        01
2     1        01
3     Null     03
```

Comment: You want to update table1 status to a value which may be different to that of table2 and set the code for that id to the code from table2?

Comment: 'I've read it is not possible to do when executing an update statement; - not exactly you can set NEW. values in a before update trigger.

Comment: Thanks, just tried this and it worked!